# How can I make a function complete before calling others in an IBAction?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift2, completionhandler

I'm having trouble understanding completion handlers.

I have a textFieldEditingDidChange IBAction that calls first a **verify()** function on the textfield input **and then an if statement** on the boolean returned by apply. **The problem is that the if statement starts before verify() has finished**.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func myTextFieldEditingDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {

        let yo = verify(myTextField.text!)            
        print("\(yo)") // it always prints "true" because verify hasn't finished

}


func verify(myText: String) -> Bool {
    var result = true
    // some code that fetches a string "orlando" on the server
    if myText == "orlando" {
         result = false
    }
    return result
}
```

How can i make the print statement, or any code, happen after verify has had timed to execute ??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
func verify(myText: String, completion: (bool: Bool)->()) {
    var result = true
    // some code that fetches a string "orlando" on the server
    if myText == "orlando" {
        result = false
    }
    completion(bool: result)
}
```

And you call it in your IBAction like this, with a trailing closure:

```
verify(myTextField.text!) { (bool) in
    if bool {
        // condition in `verify()` is true
    } else {
        // condition in `verify()` is false
    }
}
```

Note: where you say "some code that fetches a string "orlando" on the server", be careful to not set the new `completion` *after* the async call, otherwise you would still experience the same issue... *The completion should be used in the same scope as the async call result.*

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Your note was helpful too, since I did exactly the error you anticipated. Works fine now.